# When is it necessary to add the nuget package Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility

Tags: .net-core, portable-class-library, .net-standard

The description on [Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility/) confuses me.
For example, I am creating a "new style" (netstandard) Portable Library. Do I need to add this package to my dependencies when I reference an oldstyle PCL Library from my package or vice versa?

When exactly do I need to add this package to my dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a package from nuget that hasn't yet been updated for .Net Core / .Net Standard, but *does* have PCLs inside it, this package can help.

Damian Edwards talks about it here: https://youtu.be/NSjYQmu1u_k?t=36m30s